# FFMPEG - No such filter 'minterpolate'

Tags: ffmpeg

So, I am trying to run a command in FFMPEG to do motion interpolation, and this is what happens.

```
ffmpeg -i '드래곤빌리지 에피소드 영상 2화 (공식)-CYOxGwLy4mk.mkv' -filter "minterpolate='fps=60'" 60fps.mp4
```

First I run the above command to encode a video, and I get the following output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '드래곤빌리지 에피소드 영상 2화 (공식)-CYOxGwLy4mk.mkv':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:04:02.60, start: 0.007000, bitrate: 1341 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      CREATION_TIME   : 2015-09-11 04:20:30
      LANGUAGE        : und
      HANDLER_NAME    : VideoHandler
      DURATION        : 00:04:02.576000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      DURATION        : 00:04:02.601000000
File '60fps.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x1b86240] No such filter: 'minterpolate'
Error opening filters!
```

How can I fix this error? I am running Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon.

Comment: `ffmpeg -filters` will list all filters for this build. If missing, you'll have to build ffmpeg yourself or install from a newer package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ffmpeg` is too old. minterpolate filter was added on 2016-08-23 in commit b07d4a0, but you are using the FFmpeg 2.8 branch release which is from 2015-09-05.

Get a newer build: [compile](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) or just [download a static binary](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Comment: I tried compiling using this guide but still get the same error. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Comment: @EduardoPerez Ensure that you're executing the `ffmpeg` binary you compiled instead of the one from the PPA. Console output should show something like `ffmpeg version N-86794-gc61715e2c5` instead of `ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`. See the [Usage](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#Conclusion) section for more info.